# Come si dice in italiano "hottest single"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation, single-words

In inglese per parlare dei brani/album più popolari si dice *hottest single/ hottest album*.
In italiano invece come si dice? Top hit? Top brani?  Esiste un modo di dire che somigli di più a *hottest single*?

Comment: Brani/album del momento?

Answer (score 4):

I meno giovani ricorderanno sicuramente una trasmissione radiofonica che ha fatto storia in fatto di canzoni più ascoltate del momento.

> Il 6 gennaio 1967 partiva il primo numero della popolare rubrica radiofonica “[Hit Parade”](http://www.teche.rai.it/2017/01/6-gennaio-1967-inizia-hit-parade-lelio-luttazzi/), presentata da Lelio Luttazzi.
> In onda fino al 1976, tutti i venerdì all’ora di pranzo, era una vetrina settimanale dei dischi più venduti. Per anni fu un appuntamento fisso per milioni di ascoltatori e diede a Luttazzi una grande fama.

Da quella trasmissione vennero fuori alcune espressioni che rimasero nel tempo come “la canzone regina” per indicare la prima in classifica. Ai tempi si parlava di dischi “più venduti”, ora i parametri sono diversi e la notorietà dei pezzi musicali dipende da quante volte sono scaricati od ascoltati dalle varie piattaforme internet.

Espressioni come [il pezzo del momento](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3WATaB8O49F93n2Z2IAqTQcgH1IKYtBj)  o anche [i pezzi più hot del momento](https://timgate.it/intrattenimento/musica/canzoni-dance-playlist-timmusic.vum)  sono molto comuni.

Answer (score 2):

**In generale**, puoi tradurlo letteralmente con "il brano/singolo/album più caldo (del momento)" oppure con "il brano più popolare" o anche "il brano più ascoltato".

Userei invece cautela nel tradurre con l'espressione "il brano più in voga" che, sebbene corretta, rischia di suonare un po' antiquato o "accademico" in determinati contesti.

Se invece lo devi usare **come "categoria"** (ad esempio come voce di un menu di navigazione per su un sito/app) direi che è abbastanza comune usare "brani più ascoltati", "brani popolari" oppure "brani di tendenza" (che ricalca l'inglese "*trending*")

Comment: Potrebbe anche essere  "più di moda" o "più alla moda"? Si usa anche "trendy" o "di tendenza"?

Comment: @Charo, in senso generale, "di moda" o "alla moda" potrebbe andare ma, nell'ambito della musica e della domanda, direi di no. Non è *sbagliato*, semplicemente non si usa. "Di tendenza" invece può andar bene anche in ambito musicale, come avevo già indicato nella risposta. Ultima nota: la versione anglicizzata "trendy", mi sembra più comunemente usata in riferimento alla moda, al design o al costume; nell'ambito della musica direi che viene utilizzato in riferimento ad un genere musicale più che in relazione ad un album o un brano specifico.

Comment: ... ancora, in riferimeno a "trendy": direi (opinione personale) che non indichi semplicemente "ciò che *è* alla moda" ma "ciò che *ti fa apparire* alla moda". In altre parole, il suo utilizzo pone l'accento sul valore come status symbol.

Answer (score 1):

La sezione musica di YouTube italiano utilizza vari termini, i più appropriati mi sembrano "**hit**", "**di tendenza**" e "**successi**". Ad esempio: "*le hit di oggi*", "*gli album più di tendenza*", "*i successi hip hop del momento*".

Amazonmusic italiano invece utilizza termini come "**più ascoltati**" e "**top hit**" (questo a volte anche nel plurale, "**hits**"). Ad esempio: "*brani/album più ascoltati*", "*hits del momento*".

Spotify italiano utilizza anch'esso "hit" e "**popolari**". Ad esempio: "*i singoli più popolari*".

Secondo me tutti questi termini sono facilmente comprensibili e interscambiabili. L'unico che mi sembra scorretto è "hits" al plurale, perché quando si scrive in italiano i termini inglesi non vogliono la s, anche quando sono plurali ([fonte](https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_391.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In aggiunta alla precedente risposta suggerisco il termine ***[tormentone](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=tormentone)*** nella parte dell'accezione riferita ad un brano musicale:

> 1. (fam.) persona o cosa noiosa, fastidiosa, opprimente; anche, persona o cosa che viene insistentemente proposta dai media,
>    risultando tediosa e irritante: tuo figlio è un tormentone; **questa
>    canzone è il tormentone dell’estate**

Una canzone che ha un grande successo in breve tempo e viene riproposta ossessivamente dai media.

Comment: Non sono d'accordo: "tormentone" porta con sé una sfumatura negativa che "*hottest single/album*" non ha. Inoltre un "tormentone" diventa tale, per sua natura, dopo un periodo di tempo abbastanza prolungato anche se limitato ("il tormentone dell'estate", "il tormentone del 2020") mentre l'inglese "*hottest single/album*" può essere riferito ad un periodo di tempo anche molto limitato ("the hottest album of this month", "the hottest single of this week").